# Raspberry (PiHole): 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, http-status-code-500, pihole

It happened already twice today, I try to reach the dashboard and I get "500 Internal Server Error"; I can ping the raspberry but SSH does not work (connection closed by peer)

A reboot will fix the problem

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not check your server's log file for this? "500 Internal Server Error" does not sound like something that is related to SSH after all

Answer (score 0):

There is a ton of situations here, you probably need some level of monitoring on your system. If it happens "a lot" then I'd look at a partition like your `/var` partition, filling up and the OS not being able to write to it.

With the reboot, *typically* your `/tmp/` and `/var` partitions get cleaned out allowing you to administer the machine.

So, tl;dr? The best thing would be to set up some type of monitoring on your raspberry pi and watch the graphs. If you have no idea where to start, [datadog](https://osgav.run/post/datadog-rpi-network-process-metrics.html) will help you get off the ground.